# Create Clickable Title Web Part

Tags: web-part

I have a simple web part that renders data. My client asks me to create a clickable web part title.

How would you solve this problem? Because I cannot add controls to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just a URL you can add it as a property in the .webpart-file, or from your code-behind.

The property is named `TitleUrl`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.titleurl.aspx